# human_name for state in state_machine ruby gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I use gem state_machine - [Official](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine)

Each state can have 'human name'. By docs and APIs i've tried:

in my_model.rb

```
state_machine :initial => :new do
    state :new, :human_name => 'Added and not accepted'
    ...
```

in my_view.haml

```
%p= MyModel.human_state_name(@item.state_name)
%p= @item.human_state_name
```

both variants return just 'new' instead of 'Added and not accepted'. What I should do? I've made mistake in setting human_name or in getting human_name?

**Update**
Works in:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    state_machines:
      mymodel: # model name
        states:
          new: 'Added and not accepted' # state name
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to pass :human_name option to state machine. Just define translations for your language:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    state_machines:
      mymodel: # model name
        state: # state name
          states:
            new: 'Added and not accepted'
          events: # you can also define translations for the events
            some_event: 'put custom translation here'
```

Comment: Works with some another syntax =) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @dmr Would you share the other syntax that works? i have the same problem and the translations does not work if you want to pluralize states.